# Maximize chance of successful rename in ftp request

Tags: python, ftp, rename

For some background, there are some files being uploaded to a directory in an ftp, and as soon as those files start to get uploaded, I try to rename the directory until completion or another person has renamed the directory already.

```
while Time_elapsed < 200 and Grabby == False:
                try:
                    Time_elapsed = time.time() - Start_time
                    ftp.rename(current_address,next_address)
                    Grabby = True
                except Exception, e:
                    print str(Time_elapsed)
                    pass
```

Because there are other people trying to rename this file simultaneously, I want to maximize the chance I get a successful rename, is there any way to do this?